# How do I view registered syles and scripts for enqueue

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css, wp-register-style

I know that `wp_register_style()`, `wp_deregister_style()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` are used for css style registration and enqueue management. However, I am interested in viewing ALL registered styles (whether custom or by default).

Does `wp_register_style()` add the script names/locations to a table in the WordPress database? If so, which? And how can I view them? Is there a function for that or do I have to create my own?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the $wp_scripts and $wp_styles globals.